# Getting PUT 500 error when trying to update database

Tags: html, reactjs, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

I’m getting a PUT 500 error when I’m trying to update a table in my database.

[image: PUT error]

**EDIT:**
When I debug the PutPost method:
[image]

I have another method that is almost the same, that works. The difference is that in the one that doesn’t work, I use a List of images instead of just one.

PostController (HttpPut) Doesn’t work:

```
  [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutPost(int id, [FromForm] Post post, [FromForm] List<IFormFile> images)
        {
            if (id != post.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }


            _context.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;

            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                if (image != null)
                {
                    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(image.FileName);
                    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath + @"\images\postimages\", fileName);

                    using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                    {
                        await image.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }

                    Image newPostImage = new Image()
                    {
                        PostId = post.Id,
                        Url = fileName

                    };

                    _context.Images.Add(newPostImage);
                }

            }


            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!PostExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
```

Post.cs (model for controller)

```
 public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ContentTxt { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,4)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }


        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Image> Images { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    }
```

WebContext.cs

```
namespace testing_API.Models
{
    public class WebContext : DbContext
    {
        public WebContext(DbContextOptions<WebContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }




        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Images)
                .WithOne(x => x.Post)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOne(x => x.User)
                .WithMany(x => x.Posts)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);


            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                   .HasMany(x => x.Comments)
                   .WithOne(x => x.Post)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.PostId);


            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Category)
                .WithMany(x => x.Posts)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryID);



        }

    }
```

My Axios put call in react:

```
  putPost: async (item, id) => {
            const formData = new FormData(item);
            let response = await axios.put(baseApi + "posts/" + id, formData);
            return response.data;
          },
```

EditPost.js (my react component)

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";

import history from "../../../context/history";
import DbContext from "../../../context/DbContext";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const EditPost = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const context = useContext(DbContext);
  const [post, setPost] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (context.existsUser() == null) {
      history.push("/");
    }

    setUser(context.getUser());
    context.getPost(props.match.params.id).then((x) => setPost(x));
  }, [context.existsUser()]);

  const handleEdit = useCallback((event) => {
    console.log(event.target.id.value);
    event.preventDefault();
    context.putPost(event.target, event.target.id.value).then((x) => {
      context.refreshUser();
    });
  }, []);

  function getDate() {
    if (user?.dateOfBirth == null) {
      return null;
    }

    var date = "";
    date += new Date(user?.dateOfBirth).getFullYear();
    date += "-" + new Date(user?.dateOfBirth).getMonth();
    date += "-" + new Date(user?.dateOfBirth).getDate();

    return new Date(user?.dateOfBirth).toISOString().substr(0, 10);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <section className="container-fluid">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
              <h3>Edit post</h3>
              <hr />
              <Link
                to="/profile"
                className="btn btn-primary position-absolute"
                style={{ right: 15, top: 5 }}
              >
                Back
              </Link>

              <form onSubmit={handleEdit}>
                <p> {new Date(post?.date).toUTCString()}</p>
                <img type="hidden" name="image" defaultValue={post?.image} />
                {/* id */}
                <input
                  type="hidden"
                  id="id"
                  name="id"
                  defaultValue={post?.id}
                />
                {/* date */}
                <input
                  type="hidden"
                  id="date"
                  name="date"
                  defaultValue={new Date(post?.date).toUTCString()}
                />
                {/* userid */}
                <input
                  type="hidden"
                  id="userId"
                  name="userId"
                  defaultValue={post?.id}
                />
                {/* catID */}
                <input
                  type="hidden"
                  name="categoryID"
                  defaultValue={post?.categoryID}
                />
           
                {/* Title */}
                <h1>{post?.title}</h1>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="title"
                    name="title"
                    aria-describedby="titleHelp"
                    defaultValue={post?.title}
                  />
                  <small id="nameHelp">Your full name</small>
                </div>
                {/*  image */}
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="image">Image</label>
                      <input
                        type="file"
                        className="form-control-file"
                        id="image"
                        name="image"
                        aria-describedby="imageHelp"
                      />
                      <small id="imageHelp">Your profile image</small>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  {post?.images.map((image) => (
                    <div className="col-4" key={image?.id}>
                      <img
                        data-thumbnail
                        src={`APIURL`}
                        alt="post image"
                        className="img-fluid"
                      />
                    </div>
                  ))}

                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="contentTxt">Information</label>
                    <textarea
                      className="form-control"
                      id="contentTxt"
                      name="contentTxt"
                      aria-describedby="contentTxtHelp"
                      rows="7"
                      defaultValue={post?.contentTxt}
                    >
                      {post?.contentTxt}
                    </textarea>

                    <small id="contentHelp">Write somthing about youself</small>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12 my-3" style={{ minHeight: 50 }}>
                      <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                        style={floatRight}
                      >
                        Save
                      </button>
                      <p
                        id="editSuccess"
                        className="text-success btn"
                        style={{ display: "none", float: "right" }}
                      >
                        post updated
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};
// for create account button
const floatRight = {
  float: "right",
  width: "18rem",
};

export default EditPost;
```

Another question: is there a better way than to hide the input fields that doesn’t need updates? (fx UserId)

Comment: `PostController (HttpPut) Doesn’t work` Have you checked if it does reach into your action method? And you can check the request with actual posted data that you sent from browser client, then check if the data might cause model binding issue.

Comment: @FeiHan Hi. I have updated the question with an image of the output of the PutPost method in debug mode. Hope it helps!